# PHP Mobile website voice recorder with Mobile handset

Tags: php, web, mobile, voice, recorder

For my website in PHP, we are generating mobile website and have to implement a voice recoding facility via from any mobile device, do you guys know any better option to easily integrate the same with my PHP mobile website.

I have tried some Java Applets, but those are not working into iPhone / Android, so any simple tool, which can record voice with any mobile device and option save / play the recorded voice on my website and mobile both side.

Earliest help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language. Audio is a client-side issue. PHP has no native multimedia capabilities of its own. To handle voice recording, you'd need a Java or Flash applet. PHP's involvement would begin/end in acceping a file from that applet and storing it on the server.

Comment: well said Marc, thanks for your time & explanations.. i want a common solution, which runs on all mobile devices, right now Java Applet is not running on Apple, Android devices.. please share something more, if you're aware of

Comment: There is no common "runs on all platforms" solution. That's why you have iOS developers, Android developers, Symbian developers, etc... Theoretically Flash would work everywhere, but you'd have to beat some sense into Mr. Jobs' skull first for that to happen.